# Dealing with Norm, Complex situation not desired

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am working on a notebook for my calculus students and am dealing frequently with the norm of vector valued functions. I always seem to run into this kind of situation.

```
Clear[a, s, r];
r[s_] = {a Cos[s/a], a Sin[s/a]};
T[s_] = r'[s];
κ[s_] = Norm[T'[s]]
```

Where the output is:

```
(*Sqrt[Abs[Cos[s/a]/a]^2 + Abs[Sin[s/a]/a]^2]*)
```

Then I have to bring on the Simplify command to fix the problem. In this case, for example, I do:

```
κ[s_] = Simplify[Norm[T'[s]], s > 0 && a > 0]
```

Which provides the same answer students achieve when doing the problem by hand, namely, 1/a.

Am I dealing with the Norm command properly, or would folks like to give better advice?

**Update:**

Here is an idea that is extremely helpful if you are going to use these assumptions frequently in a large notebook:

```
Clear[a, s, r];
$Assumptions = a > 0 && s ∈ Reals;
r[s_] = {a Cos[s/a], a Sin[s/a]};
T[s_] = r'[s];
κ[s_] = Norm[T'[s]]
```

The output is:

```
(*Sqrt[Abs[Cos[s/a]/a]^2 + Abs[Sin[s/a]/a]^2]*)
```

But now I can quickly simplify.

```
Clear[a, s, r];
$Assumptions = a > 0 && s ∈ Reals;
r[s_] = {a Cos[s/a], a Sin[s/a]};
T[s_] = r'[s];
κ[s_] = Norm[T'[s]]//Simplify
```

The output is:

```
(*1/a*)
```

Comment: What you're doing seems to be the most reasonable answer in this case. If you want a simple result, you have to simplify. This is the only way to make use of all the assumptions.

Comment: Since all values are real, you could implement the `Norm` directly as `Sqrt[T'[s].T'[s]]`. This doesn't obviate the need for simplifying, although you have one fewer condition to specify. Rather, it merely gets rid of the `Abs`.

Comment: `\[Kappa][s_] = Norm[T'[s]] //Simplify[#, {a > 0, Element[s, Reals]}] &`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I frequently do what [march](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/29734/march) advises in a comment, especially when I do **not** want to `Simplify` but I do want a differentiable norm:

```
norm = Sqrt[#.#] &;
```

If you were going to put this in a package for students to use, then you might prefer

```
norm[v_?VectorQ] := Sqrt[v.v];
```

Of course, it's only good for real-component vectors.

Comment: Yes, I've been seeing this type of method as being most desirable. I think I'll use the Sqrt when teach multivariable calculus next semester.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/245/jens) that `Simplify` seems like the right approach.
Perhaps you would find value in making its use more terse.

Define:

```
simp[cond_: {}][expr_] :=
 Simplify[
   expr,
   Union @@ (Flatten[{$Assumptions, cond}] /.
     ({All -> #} & /@ Variables @ Level[expr, {-1}]))
 ]
```

Then you can do:

```
Norm[T'[s]] // simp[All > 0]
```

> ```
> 1/a
> ```

Or:

```
$Assumptions = {All > 0};

Norm[T'[s]] // simp[]
```

> ```
> 1/a
> ```